Trouble with Memory Allocation and Freeing in x86-64 Assembly on Windows
I'm working on a custom memory allocator in x86-64 assembly on a Windows 10 64-bit system. The allocator uses a simple first-fit strategy to manage a static memory pool. Allocating memory seems to work fine, but I encounter issues when freeing memory and updating the free list.
Here is a simplified version of my code
section .data
    free_list dq memory_start    ; Start with all memory free

    alloc_msg db "Allocating memory...", 10, 0
    free_msg db "Freeing memory...", 10, 0
    done_msg db "Done.", 10, 0
    block_addr_msg db "Freeing block at address: ", 0
    free_list_head_msg db "Free list head address: ", 0
    block_size_msg db "Block size: ", 0

section .bss
    memory_start resb 1024 * 10  ; 10KB memory pool

section .text
    global main
    extern printf, getchar

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    ; Initialize memory pool
    mov rax, memory_start
    mov qword [rax], 10240 - 8
    mov qword [rax + 8], 0

    lea rcx, [rel alloc_msg]
    call printf
    mov rcx, 128
    call allocate_memory

    lea rcx, [rel free_msg]
    call printf
    mov rdi, rax
    call free_memory

    lea rcx, [rel done_msg]
    call printf

    call getchar
    leave
    ret

allocate_memory:
    ; First-fit allocation strategy...
    ; Debugging output added...
    ; Returns allocated memory in RAX
    leave
    ret

free_memory:
    ; Debugging output shows the block to be freed and updates the free list...
    leave
    ret

print_hex:
    ; Print hex value in RAX
    leave
    ret

Here is my current output
Initial memory pool setup:
00007FF6199E91A0
Block size: 00000000000027F8
Allocating memory...
Current block address: 00007FF6199E91A0
Block size: 00000000000027F8
Freeing memory...

If you need to look at my complete code with all of the debugging steps, I'll add it to the end of the question.
Despite the messages confirming the process, the program seems to hang or terminate unexpectedly without reaching the final "Done." message. The free_memory function logs the block address and updates the free list, but something seems to go wrong, causing the program to exit or halt.
I've checked the following:

Correct alignment and size calculations.
Proper updating of the free list pointers.
No apparent stack corruption.

Here is the summary of what I need to know

What might cause this issue when freeing memory and updating the free list?
Is there a potential problem with how I'm managing the memory pool or free list?
Any suggestions on how to debug this further or common pitfalls in such implementations?

Development environment

OS: Windows 10 x64
Assembler: Nasm
Linker: Mingw-w-64
IDE: intellij

Executing Steps

nasm -f win64 EX.asm -o EX.o
gcc -m64 -o EX EX.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt
.\EX.exe

PS: The complete code with all the debugging steps I tried
section .data
    ; Pointers and variables for memory management
    free_list dq memory_start    ; Start with all memory free

    ; Logging messages
    alloc_msg db "Allocating memory...", 10, 0
    free_msg db "Freeing memory...", 10, 0
    compact_msg db "Compacting memory...", 10, 0
    done_msg db "Done.", 10, 0
    free_done_msg db "Done freeing memory.", 10, 0
    error_msg db "Error: Allocation failed.", 10, 0
    before_free_msg db "Before freeing memory...", 10, 0
    after_free_msg db "After freeing memory...", 10, 0
    dbg_msg db "Debugging message: ", 10, 0
    free_list_null_msg db "Free list is NULL", 10, 0
    block_addr_msg db "Freeing block at address: ", 0
    free_list_head_msg db "Free list head address: ", 0
    next_block_msg db "Next block address: ", 0
    current_block_msg db "Current block address: ", 0
    block_size_msg db "Block size: ", 0
    exact_fit_msg db "Exact fit: ", 0
    init_msg db "Initial memory pool setup:", 10, 0
    after_split_msg db "After splitting block:", 10, 0
    before_split_msg db "Before splitting block:", 10, 0

section .bss
    buffer resb 256  ; Buffer for testing allocations
    ; Memory pool
    memory_start resb 1024 * 10  ; 10KB memory pool

section .text
    global main
    extern printf, getchar

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32  ; Shadow space for external calls

    ; Initialize memory management (start with entire pool free)
    mov rax, memory_start
    mov qword [rax], 10240 - 8  ; Store size of free block (10KB - size for storing size)
    mov qword [rax + 8], 0      ; Set the next pointer to NULL

    ; Debug: Print initial memory pool setup
    lea rcx, [rel init_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, memory_start
    call print_hex              ; Print start address of memory pool
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rel memory_start]
    call print_hex              ; Print initial block size

    ; Example: Allocate a block of memory
    lea rcx, [rel alloc_msg]
    call printf
    mov rcx, 128   ; Example size of 128 bytes
    call allocate_memory
    test rax, rax
    jz alloc_error  ; Check if allocation failed

    ; Store something in the allocated memory
    mov byte [rax], 42  ; Example: Store the value 42

    ; Free the memory
    lea rcx, [rel free_msg]
    call printf
    mov rdi, rax
    call free_memory

    ; Compact memory (not yet implemented)
    lea rcx, [rel compact_msg]
    call printf
    ; call compact_memory

    ; Log: Done
    lea rcx, [rel done_msg]
    call printf

    ; Wait for user input before exiting
    call getchar

    ; Clean up and exit
    leave
    ret

alloc_error:
    ; Log: Allocation failed
    lea rcx, [rel error_msg]
    call printf

    leave
    ret

; Allocate memory using a simple first-fit strategy
; Input: rcx = size of memory requested
; Output: rax = pointer to allocated memory or 0 if failed
allocate_memory:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    ; Add space for storing block size
    add rcx, 8

    ; Traverse the free list to find the first block that fits
    mov rbx, [rel free_list]

.find_block:
    test rbx, rbx
    jz alloc_error_alloc   ; No suitable block found

    ; Debug: Print current block address and size
    lea rcx, [rel current_block_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, rbx
    call print_hex
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rbx]
    call print_hex

    mov rdx, [rbx]         ; Get the size of the current block
    cmp rdx, rcx
    jae allocate_here      ; If block size >= requested size, allocate here

    ; Move to the next block
    mov rbx, [rbx + 8]     ; Get the next block in the list
    jmp .find_block

allocate_here:
    ; Debug: Before splitting block
    lea rcx, [rel before_split_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, rbx
    call print_hex
    mov rax, [rbx]
    call print_hex

    ; Check if the block can be split
    sub rdx, rcx
    cmp rdx, 16            ; If leftover size is too small, don't split
    jl exact_fit

    ; Split the block
    mov rdi, rbx           ; Save current block pointer
    add rdi, rcx           ; Move to where the new block starts
    mov [rdi], rdx         ; Set the size of the new block
    mov rdx, [rbx + 8]
    mov [rdi + 8], rdx     ; Update the next pointer

    ; Debug: After splitting block
    lea rcx, [rel after_split_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, rdi
    call print_hex
    mov rax, [rdi]
    call print_hex

    ; Update the current block
    mov [rbx], rcx         ; Set size to the requested size
    mov [rbx + 8], rdi     ; Point to the new block

    ; Return the allocated block
    add rbx, 8             ; Move to the user part of the block
    mov rax, rbx
    leave
    ret

exact_fit:
    ; Exact fit, remove block from free list
    mov rdx, [rbx + 8]     ; Get the next block pointer
    mov [rel free_list], rdx   ; Update the free list head

    add rbx, 8             ; Move to the user part of the block
    mov rax, rbx
    leave
    ret

alloc_error_alloc:
    xor rax, rax           ; Return 0 on failure
    leave
    ret

; Free memory and add it back to the free list
; Input: rdi = pointer to memory to be freed
free_memory:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    ; Debug: Log the address of the block to be freed
    lea rcx, [rel block_addr_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, rdi
    call print_hex          ; Print block address in hexadecimal

    ; Move pointer back to include the size field
    sub rdi, 8

    ; Debug: Log the block size before adding to free list
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rdi]
    call print_hex          ; Print block size in hexadecimal

    ; Debug: Log the current free list head before modification
    lea rcx, [rel free_list_head_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rel free_list]
    call print_hex          ; Print free list head in hexadecimal

    ; Add block to the beginning of the free list
    mov rdx, [rel free_list]
    mov [rdi + 8], rdx     ; Set the next pointer to the current free list head
    mov [rel free_list], rdi   ; Update the free list head

    ; Debug: Log the new free list head after modification
    lea rcx, [rel free_list_head_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rel free_list]
    call print_hex          ; Print new free list head in hexadecimal

    ; Debug: Log the next block address in the free list
    lea rcx, [rel next_block_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rdi + 8]
    call print_hex          ; Print next block address in hexadecimal

    ; Debug: Log after adding back to the free list
    lea rcx, [rel free_done_msg]
    call printf

    leave
    ret

; Function to print a hexadecimal value (RAX) as a string
print_hex:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    ; Use the format specifier "%016llX" to print RAX as a 64-bit hex value
    lea rcx, [rel hex_format]
    mov rdx, rax
    call printf

    leave
    ret

section .data
hex_format db "%016llX", 10, 0

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edited:
After your suggestions, I changed the code and realized the problem occurs exactly in free_memory function. Then I added a couple more debugging steps to the free_memory.
free_memory:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 32            ; Allocate shadow space for calls

    ; Debug: Print the address to be freed
    lea rcx, [rel free_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, rdi
    call print_hex

    ; Move pointer back to include the size field
    sub rdi, 8

    ; Debug: Print the block size being freed
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rdi]
    call print_hex

    ; Add block to the beginning of the free list
    mov rdx, [free_list]
    mov [rdi + 8], rdx     ; Set the next pointer to the current free list head
    mov [free_list], rdi   ; Update the free list head

    ; Debug: Print the new free list head
    lea rcx, [rel new_head_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [free_list]
    call print_hex

    leave
    ret

section .data
new_head_msg db "New free list head:", 10, 0

Here's the latest output:
Initial memory pool setup:
00007FF7016F91A0
Block size: 00000000000027F8
Allocating memory...
Freeing memory...
Freeing memory...
0000000000000012
Block size:


First problem, you forgot to reserve shadow space in allocate_memory. Or maybe the first issue is that you did not seem to use a debugger. Anyway with that fixed I get an "Error: Allocation failed."

Next problem (still in allocate_memory) you destroy rcx which holds the requested size by all the printing multiple times. Fixing that the code runs here.

Also note that rbx is a callee saved register which works in your favor in that printf does not destroy it, but you should also preserve it for your caller.

Thanks for your advice! I implemented the changes you suggested. Allocation now works, but there seems to be an issue with freeing memory. I added more debugging steps to free_memory and I updated the question.

You can check the complete code from GitHub

rax is also destroyed by printf, that is the return value. As such mov rdi, rax will not pass the correct address to free_memory.

@Jester: I got it. Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I removed printf and the program was successfully executed!

To resolve this, I removed the problematic printf calls and rearranged the code to properly handle the freeing process without affecting the memory block. Here's the updated version of the code:
section .data
    free_list dq memory_start    ; Start with all memory free
    hex_format db "%016llX", 10, 0

    ; Logging messages
    alloc_msg db "Allocating memory...", 10, 0
    free_msg db "Freeing memory...", 10, 0
    error_msg db "Error: Allocation failed.", 10, 0
    init_msg db "Initial memory pool setup:", 10, 0
    block_size_msg db "Block size: ", 0
    done_msg db "Process done...", 10, 0
    new_head_msg db "New free list head:", 10, 0

section .bss
    buffer resb 256  ; Buffer for testing allocations
    ; Memory pool
    memory_start resb 1024 * 10  ; 10KB memory pool

section .text
    global main
    extern printf, getchar

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32  ; Shadow space for external calls

    ; Initialize memory management (start with entire pool free)
    mov rax, memory_start
    mov qword [rax], 10240 - 8  ; Store size of free block (10KB - size for storing size)
    mov qword [rax + 8], 0      ; Set the next pointer to NULL

    ; Debug: Print initial memory pool setup
    lea rcx, [rel init_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, memory_start
    call print_hex              ; Print start address of memory pool
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rel memory_start]
    call print_hex              ; Print initial block size

    ;Allocate a block of memory
    lea rcx, [rel alloc_msg]
    call printf
    mov rcx, 128   ; Example size of 128 bytes
    call allocate_memory
    test rax, rax
    jz alloc_error  ; Check if allocation failed

    ; Store something in the allocated memory
    mov byte [rax], 42  ; Example: Store the value 42

    ; Free the memory
    mov rdi, rax
    call free_memory

    ; Log: Done
    lea rcx, [rel done_msg]
    call printf

    ; Wait for user input before exiting
    call getchar

    ; Clean up and exit
    leave
    ret

alloc_error:
    ; Log: Allocation failed
    lea rcx, [rel error_msg]
    call printf

    leave
    ret

; Allocate memory using a simple first-fit strategy
; Input: rcx = size of memory requested
; Output: rax = pointer to allocated memory or 0 if failed
allocate_memory:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 32    ; Allocate shadow space for calls

    ; Preserve the requested size in rsi
    mov rsi, rcx

    ; Add space for storing block size
    add rcx, 8

    ; Traverse the free list to find the first block that fits
    mov rbx, [rel free_list]

.find_block:
    test rbx, rbx
    jz alloc_error_alloc   ; No suitable block found

    ; Get the size of the current block
    mov rdx, [rbx]
    cmp rdx, rcx
    jae allocate_here      ; If block size >= requested size, allocate here

    ; Move to the next block
    mov rbx, [rbx + 8]     ; Get the next block in the list
    jmp .find_block

allocate_here:
    ; Check if the block can be split
    sub rdx, rcx
    cmp rdx, 16            ; If leftover size is too small, don't split
    jl exact_fit

    ; Split the block
    mov rdi, rbx           ; Save current block pointer
    add rdi, rcx           ; Move to where the new block starts
    mov [rdi], rdx         ; Set the size of the new block
    mov rdx, [rbx + 8]
    mov [rdi + 8], rdx     ; Update the next pointer

    ; Update the current block
    mov [rbx], rcx         ; Set size to the requested size
    mov [rbx + 8], rdi     ; Point to the new block

    ; Return the allocated block
    add rbx, 8             ; Move to the user part of the block
    mov rax, rbx
    leave
    ret

exact_fit:
    ; Exact fit, remove block from free list
    mov rdx, [rbx + 8]     ; Get the next block pointer
    mov [rel free_list], rdx   ; Update the free list head

    add rbx, 8             ; Move to the user part of the block
    mov rax, rbx
    leave
    ret

alloc_error_alloc:
    xor rax, rax           ; Return 0 on failure
    leave
    ret

; Free memory and add it back to the free list
; Input: rdi = pointer to memory to be freed
free_memory:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 32            ; Allocate shadow space for calls

    ; Move pointer back to include the size field
    sub rdi, 8

    ; Check if the size field is zero (null check)
    mov rax, [rdi]
    cmp rax, 0
    je .skip_free

    ; Debug: Print the block size being freed
    lea rcx, [rel block_size_msg]
    call printf
    call print_hex

    ; Add block to the beginning of the free list
    mov rdx, [rel free_list]
    mov [rdi + 8], rdx     ; Set the next pointer to the current free list head
    mov [rel free_list], rdi   ; Update the free list head

    ; Debug: Print the new free list head
    lea rcx, [rel new_head_msg]
    call printf
    mov rax, [rel free_list]
    call print_hex

.skip_free:
    ; Debug: Reached the skip_free section
    lea rcx, [rel done_msg]
    call printf

    leave
    ret

; Function to print a hexadecimal value (RAX) as a string
print_hex:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    lea rcx, [rel hex_format]
    mov rdx, rax
    call printf

    leave
    ret

key changes:

Removed unnecessary printf calls: I removed the printf calls before the memory was freed to prevent any interference with memory management.
Added block size checks: I ensured that the block size is checked properly before attempting to free it.

With these changes, the program correctly handles memory allocation and freeing, ensuring that it doesn't crash due to corrupted memory. Thank you for anyone who helped me to figure it out

to prevent any interference with memory management - I think the main point there was to prevent interference with register values.  This is why we use debuggers that allow single-stepping and inspecting registers / memory in an unmodified program instead of debug-prints, especially in assembly language.

Your allocate_memory function still wouldn't be safe to call from C since it doesn't follow the standard calling convention.  It destroys its caller's RSI and RBX.  (Also, it's strange that allocate_here has a non-dot name, but it appears to just be part of allocate_memory, not a separate function.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170

@PeterCordes: Mmm... I felt something wrong. The program executed correctly so I ignored it. Thank you so much for your explanation and references. I'm a newbie to assembly and complicated to understand some points. It would be appreciated if you could provide an answer with the corrected code. :)
